# React Native Android only: nested Touchable's, multiple responders to gestures

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a fairly simple RN app with a layout similar to this:

[image]

As shown in my image, I have four `Touchable` columns equally splitting the screen.

Everything works fine. But here is what I'm trying to do now: wherever a user touches the screen, I need to append an element where the touch interaction occured and on top of everything.

[image]

First, I naively added a new `TouchableWithoutFeedback` on top of my other views, but this simply prevented `onPress` to be fired on those other views.

Then I began to realize that this was not as simple as I thought and took a look to the [Gesture Responder System](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html#content). I think I got the concept but I didn't achieve anything with it yet...

Is it possible to let `onPress` events to bubble up through every layers ?

Comment: This is infuriating coming from the browser. I've grown quite accustomed to being able to handle the same event different ways from different component layers with different concerns. Hope you get an answer!